# PHP: Better way to replace string value in array with an array?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP so I'm not sure how to optimize this code.

I execute a Python script from PHP and the `$output` variable returned is an array of arrays.

```
exec (" /Users/$USER/anaconda/bin/python /Applications/MAMP/cgi-bin/Evaluation1.py",$output)
```

Each array within the `$output` array contains one string value separated by commas. So `$output` is Array ( [0] => 1, 好, 0 [1] => 2, 妈妈, 3), etc.

In each array within the `$output` array, I use explode on the string value to create an array, and add it to my new `$output` array called `$output2`

```
$output2 = array();
foreach($output as $value){
$myArray = explode(',', $value);
$output2[] = $myArray;
}
```

Is there a way to just replace/overwrite the string value in the arrays within `$output` with the new array, instead of adding each item to a new `$output2` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [array_walk](http://www.php.net/array_walk) to do the loop over output. You pass in a callback function that is called for each value by reference so any changes to the passed in value stick to the array.

Test data:

```
$output = array(
    '1,A,2',
    '2,B,3',
    '3,C,4'
);
```

PHP >= 5.3.0

```
array_walk($output, function(&$val){ $val = explode(',', $val); } );
```

Older PHP

```
function mySplit(&$val){
    $val = explode(',', $val);
}
array_walk($output, 'mySplit');
```

Both output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => A
            [2] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => B
            [2] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => C
            [2] => 4
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some great answers already. Just adding this for completeness.

```
$ar = array(
    "1,2,3",
    "4,5,6"
);

foreach($ar as $k => $v) {
    $ar[$k] = explode(',', $v);
}
```

Wold be interesting to see a a performance difference of the different methods although i doubt it would be much.

Comment: I was actually curious about the benchmarks also so I wrote/ran a little test. Over 1000 iterations, [my code with anonymous function:](http://codepad.viper-7.com/35NZZ1) `32.21ms`, [my code with defined function:](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gUiNZe)`27.76ms`, [your code:](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rb6zjj) `21.27ms`, [derp's code:](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tegghB) `28.17ms`. You can click on the links to see each test. While they are all close together and the difference is negligible, I think it is interesting that the anony function does offer a little overhead with your foreach winning.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn awesome! thanks for running the tests.